# Where does gradle build store anonymous inner classes in Java?

Tags: java, gradle, build, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I was recently found out that when we compile a java file containing inner classes, separate files are generated for each class.

But in Gradle build only one .class file is generated. Where does gradle store all inner classes?

Comment: That's not true, inner classes are generated too. Give us your test case.

Comment: Yes you are right, inner classes are generated. But problem was they were hidden in intellij, so I was not able to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle delegates compilation to the Java compiler and will thus produce class files according to the specification of the language.

So inner classes will appear in separate class files.